# object Object in text box

Tags: angularjs

i have a bootstrap model

```
<div id="otpModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Enter OTP</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-otp" name="otp" ng-submit="enterOtp()" >

                        <div class="row col s6">
                                     <p>A verification code has been sent to your mobile by SMS. Please enter the verification code.
                                        </p>
                                    <input type="text" id="otp" placeholder="enter your OTP code" name="otpName" class="validate" maxlength="6" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{4,6}$/" ng-model="otp" required>     
                        </div>
                        <p id="otpMsg" style="color:#e52424"></p>

                        <a href="#" ng-click="resendOtp()">Resend ?</a>
                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form-otp.$invalid" class="waves-effect waves-light btn done">
                                   <i class="material-icons left">done</i> Done
                        </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
          </div>
```

i have a controller in which enterOtp() & resendOtp() is defined. Problem is text box with name "otpName" is showing  [object Object]  in it .

Comment: post the js code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
ng-model="otp"
```

to

```
ng-model="otp.name"
```

You are probably using the wrong field as ng-model.

Comment: may be your right @tpsilva but we can't decide as we dont what's calling  in controller

Comment: Yep, I've made a long shot.

Comment: Thanks, perfect for me :)

Comment: Glad I could help @Harshsachdev. If it solved your problem, consider accepting as answer. :)